# Struggles with django-storages, s3, and heroku

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I added django-storages to requirements and installed it via pip. I got it such that python manage.py collectstatic --settings=projectapp.settings.staging actually puts files on my Amazon s3 bucket, named 'project' for the purposes of this post. However, when I run the server (using staging settings--or visiting staging.project.herokuapp.com), I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'.

Why is this?

Comment: Also--I think I just identified a solution. Line 458 of django-storages.backends.s3boto.py has a function 'url' that calls name=self._normalize_name and self._cleane_name which seems to assume that the name passed into url by django's staticfiles app is 'SafeText' class, but it appears to be passing in an 'ImageFieldFile' so if I add--if name.__class__.__name__ == 'ImageFieldFile': name = name.__unicode__(), then it works.

Comment: Figured it out and reported bug in django-storages at: https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/issue/179/attributeerror-imagefieldfile-object-has.

Basically, django-storages appears to be assuming that it gets passed strings by staticfiles.py (where the static template tag is). However, with image file fields it is getting passed non-strings. So use model.imagefilefield|stringformat('s') to make sure you only pass in strings. Ok workaround for now.

Comment: You got downvoted (I imagine) because you haven't given enough information (stack trace, what you've investigate, what *does* work etc.) in your post and it's badly formatted.

Comment: That bug report is now marked as resolved.